# jQuery Sortable moves my <tr> out of my <tbody>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's my JSfiddle if you want to see what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/qjADE/

I have HTML that looks like this on initial load:

```
<table class="sorted_table">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1" class="homepage-slide-data admin-homepage-slide-list">...</tr>
    <tr id="2" class="homepage-slide-data admin-homepage-slide-list">...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice how I have two `<tr>...</tr>`s

No problem with that. However, if I drag the top  (tr#1) to the bottom, and try dragging the new top  (now tr#2 since the order switched) to the bottom, it stops working. I checked the HTML, and it looks like dragging the top  to the bottom multiple times does two (unwanted) things:

1. The placeholder stays at the bottom, it doesn't update/move anymore.
2. If you open up firebug and watch html, you'll see that the `</tbody>` gets pushed up so that the `<tr>`s are no longer encased by the `<tbody>...</tbody>`:

   #...
     ...

Here's my JS for customizing jquery sortable:

```
$('.sorted_table').sortable({
    containerSelector: 'table',
    itemPath: '> tbody',
    itemSelector: 'tr.admin-homepage-slide-list',
    placeholder: '<li class="placeholder"/>', #<-- I tried tr instead of li too, same result
    pullPlaceholder: true,
    onDrop: function () {
        var id_list = new Array();
        $('.sorted_table tr.homepage-slide-data').each(function(index) {
            id_list[index] = $(this).attr("id");
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/admin/homepage_slides/update_order',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"new_order": id_list},
            dataType: 'script'
        });
    }
})
```

P.S. I'm open to trying other plugins. If you know anything with similar functionality for table row ordering, let me know.

Comment: Should your container be `tbody`?

Comment: You mean change the `containerSelector` option?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to this: http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/